Window 10 pro installation on Hyper-V uses pin authentication, but RDP client wants a username and password
The RDP prompts me for my ms credentials. On previous installations the iso would automatically create a user name local to the vm. I tried signing in with my ms account but this does not work.
RDP authenication prompt
I would like to find a solution where I can either configure windows 10 pro to prompt for user name and password I can create that is not linked to my Microsoft username-as this really confusing. I don't see any clear way to do this when I go into sign in options. There seems to be some assumption that username and password should be the same as my credentials, but as I said before my ms credential don't authenticate during the rdp session.It should be noted during the installation I was not prompted to create a username and password only this pin. It is terribly inconvenient to work with Hyper-v in absence of an rdp session. I would appreciate any solution anyone can provide for connecting  windows 10 pro installation to a rdp session.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

How are you specifying the username? How you specify a Microsoft Account username is different from a username not associated with Microsoft Account. As is how you specify a username for a remote machine rather then the local machine (which is typically the default). Keep in mind even if the username on both machines are identical the actual Windows user is not identical. You must be explicit in what user you want to use for a RDP connection

@Ramhound, yes by default the installation links your ms account with the user's installation and creates a pin login. The MS account  credentials cannot be used to login into an RDP session because it isn't linked during the installation-only the pin number which the RDP client will not accept. A local username and password must be created for this explicit purpose.

My solution was to create local username and password, since the RDP client doesn't seem to support pin authentication.
GUI for adding users
The RDP client is what we sw engineers use to connect to the virtual instance of whatever os we are testing, because the window hyper-v defaults to being displayed in isn't viable- we can't for example do a screen capture or a copy & paste and the resolution is very poor. To elaborate further- the RDP client doesn't accept a pin number for credentials- it prompts for username and password
RDP authentication prompt
It seems the installation by design defaults to linking an ms account with the account on the local instance that is being installed. The accepted answer for having the instance default to a local user and not a ms account is to ensure that the instance is offline as the installation process is happening.
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/set-up-windows-10-without-account/d7c08c1a-0fcc-49ac-96ac-297879dbee6f
Hyper-v network adaptper

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
